# サブプロセスの標準出力を取得したい

Tags: python

親プロセスが子プロセスを起動し、子プロセスは親プロセスがコマンドを打つたびに結果を返す。
コマンドと結果のやり取りは標準入出力で一行ずつやり取りする。
ということを考えています。

次のような実験を行ったのですが、下のようなエラーが出てうまくいきません。どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

メイン:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

with subprocess.Popen(
    [sys.executable, "sub.py"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    encoding="utf-8"
) as p:
    print("hoge", file=p.stdin)
    # TODO: 受け取り処理
```

sub.py:

```py
from sys import stderr, stdin, stdout

for line in stdin:
    # 通る 正常にファイルができる
    with open("out.txt", "a") as f:
        print(line, file=f)

    # 通る 正常にコンソールに表示される
    print(line, file=stderr)

    # 通らない
    print(line)
```

エラー:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp932'>        
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

環境:
windows10
python 3.9.5

Comment: 子プロセスは Python固定ですか？ Pythonから子プロセスとして Python呼び出すのなら [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/multiprocessing.html) などがあり, プロセス間通信が(Popenに比べ) 容易です

Comment: 現在直面している問題に関してはpython固定です。ですが前々から出来たらよいなと考えていたので子プロセスの言語を限定しない方法は知りたいです。

Comment: 関連質問: [scanfを含むCプログラムを他の言語からインタラクティブに実行したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/61444)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pipe を `flush` するという方法もあるかと思います。

**main.py**

```py
import subprocess
import sys

with subprocess.Popen(
    [sys.executable, "sub.py"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    encoding="utf-8",
) as p:
    for msg in ['hoge', 'fuga', 'piyo']:
        print(msg, file=p.stdin, flush=True)
        line = p.stdout.readline()
        print(line.strip())
```

**sub.py**

```py
from sys import stderr, stdin, stdout

for line in stdin:
    print(f'OK: {line.strip()}', flush=True)
```

**実行**

```sh
$ python3 --version
Python 3.9.5
$ python3 main.py
OK: hoge
OK: fuga
OK: piyo
```

Answer (score 0):

`PIPE`を使っていて, 子プロセスから文字列出力しているのに, 親プロセスで受け取っていないから例外が出てるようですね

`# TODO: 受け取り処理` 辺りに処理を追加するとよいかも
(追記: この処理は, まとめて送信・受信, をおこなうもので「交互にやり取り」は**できません**)

```py
    stdout = p.communicate()[0]
    print(f'{stdout=}')
    p.stdin.close()
```

---

あと, `stdin`に `print`するのも 考えてみれば奇妙に映るかもなので, コメントに記す, それっぽいコードにする？など対策あってもよいかも

```py
    # print 使わないで書き込むとか
    p.stdin.write('hello world\n')
    p.stdin.write('this is a pen\n')
```

```py
    # print 使うにしてもそれっぽいこと示すとか
    from contextlib import redirect_stdout
    with redirect_stdout(p.stdin):
        print('hello world\n')
        print('this is a pen\n')
```

---

##### (コメントにより)追記

親プロセスと子プロセスで「**交互**」にやりとり行うのですね？

その場合, Python同士なら [multiprocessing --- プロセスベースの並列処理](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/multiprocessing.html) が利用可能でプロセス間通信機能もそれなり豊富です

`subprocess.Popen` 使用する場合, そのままだと標準入力待ちで制御が奪われます(戻ってこない)
なので, スレッドあるいは(プロセス, あるいは)非同期処理を併用することになるでしょう

- 非同期処理 (stackoverflow.com) [python asyncio how to read StdIn and write to StdOut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303607/python-asyncio-how-to-read-stdin-and-write-to-stdout)

---

##### さらに追記

generator使う方法があるようです

(元記事からの抜粋)

```py
def get_lines():

    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        if line:
            yield line

        if not line and proc.poll() is not None:
            break
```

組み合わせが問題ですが, 例えばこんなふうに (記事に合わせ `p` => `proc` として記述)

```py
    gen = get_lines()

    proc.stdin.write('hello world\n')
    proc.stdin.flush()
    print(next(gen))

    proc.stdin.write('this is a pen\n')
    proc.stdin.flush()
    print(next(gen))
```

参考: [Pythonのsubprocessで標準出力をリアルタイムに取得する](https://qiita.com/megmogmog1965/items/5f95b35539ed6b3cfa17)

Comment: この方法の場合、1つ目の結果を受け取ることはできましたが、2つ目のコマンドを送信しようとすると、`I/O operation on closed file.` と出て失敗しました

Comment: @v..snow [Popen.communicate](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py#L1105) から、"Send data to stdin and **close it**."